# Create a virtual directory between two machines

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, network-storage

I have two linode VPS. I want to create a virtual directory that can be read/write from both machines. The actual data should be stored in /var/myapp/data on two machines. I don't need any redundant data since reliability is not a concern here. All my data in virtual directory should be shared somehow between both my machines.

My PHP App should be able to read/write from the virtual directory
Both machines are Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure NFS on both servers as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Comment: So I install NFS Server on both machines?

Comment: You can have NFS client and server on both servers. But, the requried is to have NFS server on one machine and NFS client on the other one. The NFS client will access the folder remotely. The NFS server will access the folder locally as normal.